# Error while trying set Environment variables in linux using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

So I am trying to set environment variables using my shell Script. The script takes some inputs from the user and then i have to set those inputs in the environment variable. I am using two shell Script for the same but i am getting permission denied errors.

**Script 1**

```
DEFAULT_NAME="sample"
read -p "Enter your Name: [$DEFAULT_NAME]: " USER_NAME
if [ -z "$USER_NAME" ]
then
    USER_NAME=$DEFAULT_NAME
else
    USER_NAME=$USER_NAME
fi
source setEnv.sh
```

**Script 2**

```
echo -e "export NAME=${USER_NAME}" >> /etc/profile.d/nameenv.sh
```

Comment: Your 2nd script has to run as root, since `/etc/profile.d/nameenv.sh` can only be written by root.

Comment: As indicated by the comments to @David's answer this appears to be an example of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). No one can figure out what problem you're trying to solve. Note that in UNIX like operating systems (e.g., Linux) environment variables are private to each process and inherited from their parent process.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `if` condition in **Script 1** is wrong, you probably want to test `$USER_NAME` instead.
If you are using *bash*, you can replace the whole `if` statement with:

```sh
USER_NAME=${USER_NAME:-$DEFAULT_NAME}
```

In **Script 2** are you sure that you want to append a new line to `/etc/profile.d/nameenv.sh`, every time you execute the script? The last declaration will hide the preceding ones.

Finally, note that you need `root` privilege to write in `/etc/profile.d`. Are you running the script as a privileged user?

[Edit] Trying to guess what you are trying to do here. If you need that USER_NAME is redefined for the user's current session (and not system-wide), just replace the last line in **Script 1** with:

```sh
export USER_NAME
```

and remove **Script 2**. If you want to make it permanent (again, for the current user only), modify **Script 2** to write the variable declaration in `~/.bash_profile` instead.

Comment: I have edited the script 1 now coming on to the script 2 i want whenever the user runs script1 the environment variable gets updated. Also is there a way we can do this without being the root user or any other method help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some context is needed here. What are you trying to achieve?
Files in `/etc/profile.d/` are not user-specific. Do you really want any user to be able to redefine `USER_NAME` for everyone in the system?

Comment: So basically the username is just an example lets say i have to switch DatabaseID or something like that .

Comment: The problem of course is not the variable name, but who (and when) should be affected by the change. Were Script 2 allowed to do that `echo`, *all* the users (including `root`) at the next login would have the new value in their environment.
Is this *really* what you want to do? Definitely, only `root` should be able to do that...

Comment: Yes you are right only root user should be able to do so. Also is there any way by which the environment variables changes are reflected without logging in again.

Comment: You can modify a variable in the shell's environment at any time, but it won't be picked up by already running processes. The environment is copied (provided that you `EXPORT`ed the variable) to new processes when they are forked by the shell.
Again, if you could add more details about your use case, you'd probably get more sensible answers.